# Find in the last day of the month using calendar on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar

I am trying to change the last day allowed in my calendar Widget based on the current date or fix date.

The code below is using a date as a default start date and I need to allow the user to select between this date and date + 3 months later.

```
val maxDay = Calendar.getInstance() 

setSelectedDate(currentShipDate.toDate())

maxDay.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3)

state().edit()
     .setMinimumDate(minDay.time)
     .setMaximumDate(maxDay.time)
     .commit()
```

The `maxDay` is now set to 3 months later using the `currentShipDate`. However, I am looking to allow the user to also select a date until the end of the 3rd months.

For example, if the ship happened in 21st July, you can change the shipping date til 31st October (instead of 21st October)

For example, if the ship happened in 10th July, you can change the shipping date til 31st October (instead of 10st October)

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Consider using `LocalDate` rather then the outdated `Date` and `Calendar`. It’s much nicer to work with and matches your requirements much better. If programming for Android API level under 26, use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), the Android Backport of java.time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

1. Instead of adding 3 months, add 4 --> `maxDay.add(Calendar.MONTH, 4)`
2. Set the day of the month to 1 --> `maxDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)`
3. Subtract one day --> `maxDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)`

This will give you the last day of the third month.